# PHPMailer - Error al ejecutar send()

Tags: php, xampp

estoy intentando mandar un email via PHPMailer pero me da un error que no se solucionar

```php
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer-master\src\Exception.php';
require 'D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer-master\src\PHPMailer.php';
require 'D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer-master\src\SMTP.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
$name = $_POST['fullname'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);


try{
    //Lenguaje
    $mail->setLanguage('es', '/optional/path/to/language/directory/');

    //configuracion del servidor
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       ='smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    //si la autentificacion es false no hace faltael user ni pass
    $mail->Username   = 'user@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'SSL';//PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //a quien manda
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    //a quien le llega
    $mail->addAddress('something@gmail.com', 'Nombre Opcional');     // Add a recipient
    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = "Contacto:".$asunto;
    $mail->Body    = $mensaje."<br> TELEFONO:".$telefono."<br>";
  //  $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

  $mail-­>send();

  echo "Mensaje enviado!!";

  }catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Error al enviar el mensaje: " . $mail­>ErrorInfo;
  }

?>
```

Warning: Use of undefined constant ­ - assumed '­' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer-master\src\form_contactar.php on line 53

Notice: Object of class PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer could not be converted to number in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer-master\src\form_contactar.php on line 53

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer-master\src\form_contactar.php on line 53

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function send() in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer-master\src\form_contactar.php:53 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer-master\src\form_contactar.php on line 53

La linea 53 es el "$mail->Send()".

Comment: ¿Seguro que tienes bien instalado `PHPMailer`? Y, es raro que estés creando tus archivos en la carpeta fuente de la misma librería ¿? Esto, tampoco creo que esté bien configurado: `/optional/path/to/language/directory/`

Comment: He instalado PHPMailer con Composer y me sigue dando el mismo problema no se que puede ser